# How can I implement retry functionality using annotation?

Tags: java, annotations, try-catch

I'm looking for a way to turn this:

```
   public void thisFunction(int num) {
        try {
            code..
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            thisFunction(num);
        }
    }
```

into something like this:

```
@RetryNullException3Times
public void thisFunction(int num) {
    code..
}
```

Is there a way to do this with annotation or am I being too optimistic? if not what's the easiest way to implement this?

Comment: Have a look at [Spring Retry](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-retry)

Comment: In order to use spring retry, do I have to use spring server? I tried to use jcabi-aspects but I didn't manage to make it work. Posted different question about it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64537064/why-jcabi-aspects-annotations-doesnt-work

Comment: No, it's not neccessary (see https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-retry#-additional-dependencies)